# Facebook social login | Uppercase username conflicts with existing lowercase usernames

Tags: facebook

In my application, during registration, any uppercase letter in the username is converted to lower case.  E.g. If I sign up as `JohnSmith`, the app will create the username `johnsmith`.  This is done so that there is no confusion when accessing a user profile on the website - `mysite.com/user/johnsmith` and `mysite.com/user/JohnSmith` will go to the same user's profile.

I have Facebook's social login set up, and Facebook automatically generates a username that capitalizes the first and last name.  E.g. if my Facebook name is John Smith, Facebook will generate the username `JohnSmith` in the application.

This creates a problem.  If there is already a username in the database named 'johnsmith', Facebook goes ahead and generates 'JohnSmith' anyways, creating a conflict.

Is that a way I can modify Facebook's registration so that the username is always converted to lowercase?

Comment: What Facebook registration?

Comment: @WizKid [Facebook Login for Developers, Web Version](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/web)

Comment: Facebook Login does not generate a username.

Comment: First of all, your database should not allow this to begin with - declare the field as unique, with a case-insensitive collation. Then, if the next user record insertion fails due to that, choose a different value for the user name - like f.e. the app-scoped user id. (You can still offer the user to change it later ...)

Comment: @WizKid My fault.  I am using `django-social-auth` to handle Facebook's login.  I assumed FB created the username, but actually `django-social-auth` does.